# spin the pin game - iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, spinner

I need to create a game for a spinner. Just like attached image.
[image]

User can spin the pin and it will keep on spinning according to swipe velocity.
Please let me know how can i achieve this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read http://www.raywenderlich.com

He has taken a lot of care in creating a great valuable resource for learning [iPhone development](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), animation in particular. You'll be ready in no time :D

In a nutshell, there are three ways you can do this.

- use Cocos2D
- Use CoreAnimation
- Use UIView's animation methods, but I'd favor the other two solutions, especially Cocos2D since I like it :D

Comment: :D hm I also prefer Cocos2D but havn't done anything in Cocos2D yet :)

Comment: Try it, it will be a thrill ;)